# Target device api level(API 19) too low for Instant run Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-run

I just connected my phone to android studio for development and debugging. When I click on Instant run icon(Android studio 2.3.3), It says  `Target device api level(API 19) too low for Instant run`. How could I enable instant run on my device.

I have Samsung note 2(GT-N7100) and android 4.4.2

Every time I click on `run` and `debug` icon, It restart my app and then install apk again.

I have another phone (Samsung note 5), android 7. On this device instant run works fine, But I want this feature on another device.

I know this might be of topic question, But I really want to enable instant run.

Edit: I mean If I upgrade my android version, will this work. Then I will root my phone and install custom firmware.

Comment: What about "Target device api level(API 19) too low for Instant run" do you not understand?

Comment: unplug your device uninstall your apk then plug in your USB and install your app

Comment: yes @TimCastelijns, I undertstand the  "Target device api level(API 19) too low for Instant run". I want to know is there another way to enable this.

Comment: @ysl I did this. Not working

Comment: I think you don't understand it. It says the level is too low to enable it

Comment: ok, @TimCastelijns, I am editing my question

Comment: yes it will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the current behavior for Android Run. [From the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run):

> The Apply Changes action is available only when you meet the following
>   conditions:
>
> - Build your app using a debug build variant.
> - Use Android plugin for Gradle version 2.3.0 or higher.
> - Set minSdkVersion to 15 or higher in your app's module-level build.gradle file.
> - **Deploy your app to a target device running Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher.**

---

You can try [JRebel for Android](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel-for-android/) and see if it works for you. They offer a free version that has the same functionality as instant run.

Answer (score 1):

Disable Instant Run, then run `app`.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 2.3 and higher, Instant Run significantly reduces the time it takes to update your app with code and resource changes. After deploying your app to a target device running Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher, you can click Apply Changes.

Your device needs api lvl 21 or above to be able instant run.

Comment: thanks for ur responce, Is there another way to make this possible.

Comment: Not that i know of, some phones just don't have the possibility to update firmware /software due to age. So nothing much to do other than run an emulator with 21+ and if you are debugging versions less than this, then you just have to do it the old fashioned way

Comment: What if I root my phone and install custom firmware.

Comment: Havn't tried, but if you can make your phone get api lvl 21+ then you will be able to do instant run

Comment: JRebel for android...I have alternate option